# Errors opening Geospatial PDF in QGIS 3.8.3

Tags: qgis, gdal, qgis-3, geospatial-pdf, geopdf

I'm a complete QGIS newbie so bear with me if I'm missing something obvious...

I'm unable to open GeoPDF's that I've downloaded from USGS's The National Map (TNM) site. This is the error that I get in the QGIS Log:

```
2019-09-24T12:44:03     CRITICAL    Invalid Layer : GDAL provider Cannot open GDAL dataset /Users/jeff/Downloads/IL_Englewood_20120827_TM_geo.pdf:
             `/Users/jeff/Downloads/IL_Englewood_20120827_TM_geo.pdf' not recognized as a supported file format.
             Raster layer Provider is not valid (provider: gdal, URI: /Users/jeff/Downloads/IL_Englewood_20120827_TM_geo.pdf
```

When I run gdalinfo on the file I get this:

```
gdalinfo ~/Downloads/IL_Englewood_20120827_TM_geo.pdf                 
ERROR 4: `/Users/jeff/Downloads/IL_Englewood_20120827_TM_geo.pdf' not recognized as a supported file format.
gdalinfo failed - unable to open '/Users/jeff/Downloads/IL_Englewood_20120827_TM_geo.pdf'.
```

From everything I've seen online GeoPDFs should be fully supported in QGIS 3.8.3 and gdal 2.4.1. I can also open the file in the standard Apple Preview app without trouble.

Here's my QGIS "About" output if that's helpful:
[image]

Comment: Perhaps a platform issue? On Windows, GeoPDFs seem to load fine.

Comment: I have bootcamp so I installed QGIS on Windows 10 just now and could get the file to load but not render on the map view. :/ Seems like a slightly different issue but still an issue.

Comment: What happens if you open the geopdf in a normal pdf viewer?

Comment: @csk It just opens as normal and looks like a standard PDF of the map.